# SpringBoot CrudRepository trying to update instead of create new entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, crud-repository

Spring Boot save method is trying to update and returns error like:

> org.springframework.dao.IncorrectUpdateSemanticsDataAccessException:
> Failed to update entity [com.xx.xx.Account@78a31407]. Id [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJzUn.png) not found
> in database.

But my database is completely empty and I want to add **new** Entity. Here is the screenshots:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/banking/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity addAccount(@Validated @RequestBody Account account) throws IOException {
    if(!account.getType().equals("TL")  && !account.getType().equals("Altın")  && !account.getType().equals("Dolar")) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Invalid Account Type: " + account.getType());
    }

    System.out.println(account.getId());
    account.setLastDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
    BankingLogger.writeAccountToTheFile(account);

    AccountCreateSuccessResponse res = new AccountCreateSuccessResponse("Account Created", account.getId());
    this.repository.save(account);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(res);
}
```

and here is the request json:

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "name" : "Doğukan",
        "surname" : "Gülyaşar",
        "email" : "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "tc" : "123123123",
        "type" : "Dolar",
        "isDeleted": "false"
}
```

Comment: Kindly add the code for the Account entity in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the id from the payload. Create or update logic is triggered by having or not having id. If the id is set beforehand, the entity with specified id is updated, otherwise new entity is created and id will be assigned by the database.

Comment: Yes! Genious answer and correct. Also, I was generating random ID in the Account model and deleted that method as well. It works now. Thanks a lot.